# Problems with importing FORTRAN data in R

Tags: r, fortran

I have this [.DAT file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/q1k2hb6z4hwgeho/ANDRICH.DAT?dl=0) apparently from FORTRAN. I tried:

```
read.fortran("ANDRICH.DAT",header = TRUE, format="8F1.0")
```

but is not working. I am getting the following error message:

```
Error in read.table(file = FILE, header = header, sep = sep, 
row.names = row.names,  : 
more columns than column names
```

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance!

The data file looks like:

```
$ 8
$ HIDEOUS
$ LIFESACRED
$ INEFFECTIV
$ DONTBELIEV
$ WISHNOTNEC
$ MUSTHAVEIT
$ DETERRENT
$ CRIMDESERV
$ (8f1.0)
01100000
01100000
01100000
01100000
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to some Googling:

> "The FORTRAN input format for these data is (8F1.0) where “F1.0” means
>   that a variable is stored in one column and that there are no implicit
>   decimals. This format is reiterated without any space 8 times for the
>   8 variables in the data set."

[Source](http://www.uni-goettingen.de/en/ue/download/f9263f76038e6c5adc16e2549bbc8541.pdf/foli3.pdf)

Skip the first lines until you hit actual data, and use the format specified in the file `8F1.0`:

```
output <- read.fortran("ANDRICH.DAT", format="8F1.0", skip=10)
```

And you could grab the names using `readLines`:

```
names(output) <- gsub("\\$ ","",readLines("ANDRICH.DAT",n=9)[-1])
```

Results in:

```
#  HIDEOUS LIFESACRED INEFFECTIV DONTBELIEV WISHNOTNEC MUSTHAVEIT DETERRENT CRIMDESERV
#1       0          1          1          0          0          0         0          0
#2       0          1          1          0          0          0         0          0
#3       0          1          1          0          0          0         0          0
#4       0          1          1          0          0          0         0          0
#etc
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the top of the file:

```
$ 8
$ HIDEOUS
$ LIFESACRED
$ INEFFECTIV
$ DONTBELIEV
$ WISHNOTNEC
$ MUSTHAVEIT
$ DETERRENT
$ CRIMDESERV
$ (8f1.0)
01100000
01100000
01100000
01100000
11100000
11100000
11100000
11100000
11100000
11100000
11100000
11100000
11100000
```

I don't know why it would be a "FORTRAN-file". Looks to be a file with a header delimited by dollar signs with first entry the number of fiels, then next N lines being the names and then a fixed width file.

If you skipped the first 10 lines and then used read.fwf with width=1 you should be able to get success.

Comment: I am not sure to be honest if it is a fortran-file. But i did the same with the readLines command but i still don't get how to read the table. Additionaly, i think you are right that the first entry shows the number of the fields but i do not understand the appearance of the last field (8f1.0) in this table.

Comment: we can surmise the `0`'s and `1`'s were stored as floats in fortran, the `8f1.0` format descriptor writes them compactly without decimal points or spaces.